# Adding custom instructions to an UnPublish transaction

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, 2013

We have a custom deployer which stores DCPs in a third party data store. In order to un-publish those DCPs I need to send the deployer a custom value and key.

By default, an unpublish transaction package contains a `transaction.xml` and an `instructions.xml`. Is there any way to either add to these, or add additional xml files to the package?

Answer (score 13):

The problem here is that it is an unpublish operation and no templates are executed and we cannot use the AddInstructions method available in the RenderedItem class.

As an alternative there is a non documented extension point called a TransportHandler, you need to implement the ITransportHandler interface that is located in a GAC assmebly `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Transporting.dll`.

This interface gives you access to the TransportPackage and you can manipulate it when an item is certainly unpublished.

Here a code sample.

```
public class CustomTransportHandler : ITransportPackageHandler {
    private XmlDocument _instructionsDocument;

    public CustomTransportHandler(TransportPackage package) {
        _instructionsDocument = package.InstructionsDocument;
    }

    public void HandleItemForPublishing(object item, XmlElement parentElement) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public XmlElement HandleRenderedItemForPublishing(RenderedItem renderedItem, XmlElement parentElement) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void HandleResolvedItemForUnPublishing(ResolvedItem resolvedItem) {
        XmlElement customElement = _instructionsDocument.CreateElement("CustomElement");
        customElement.InnerText = "CustomValue";
    }
}
```

You can configure it in the Tridion.ContentManager.config file.

```
<transporting rootStorageFolder="c:\Temp">
    <mappings>

    </mappings>
</transporting>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: great answer and thanks for sharing.  What's the impact on Supportability by using this extension, i.e. can a service pack or version.next make use of it incompatible?

Comment: Since it is a not documented feature, R&D can change it, it is a cool and advanced extension point, but can be changed in future releases.