# Adding custom instructions

Tags: web8.5, content-manager, external-integrations

Just reading [Adding custom instructions to an UnPublish transaction](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/adding-custom-instructions-to-an-unpublish-transaction).

Does anyone know if the split between **RenderedItem.AddInstruction** (for publish) and **ITransportHandler** (for unpublish) is still the only way to add custom instructions on both a publish and an unpublish in 8.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: it is the preferred way, yes.

Longer answer:

- For unpublish you can **only** use the `ITransportHandler`.
- For publish you can use both the `RenderedItem.AddInstruction` and `ITransportHandler`, but it's better to use the `AddInstruction` because it's an API call and not direct XML manipulation. Note that you can use the `RenderedItem.AddInstruction` from two places: Templating, or from a Custom Renderer. It depends on your needs.

PS. Some shameless self promoting, but feel free to see my [talk](https://vimeo.com/290357613) from this year's TDS. It's related to your question.